# Ember deploy script failing on specific npm package

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, npm-install

I'm trying to deploy to my staging environment using `ember deploy` and continue to get this error which breaks the build

`An error occurred in the constructor for ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile`

I tracked down the issue via guess and checking to a specific handlebars template, that once commented out stopped the problem and allowed me to finish the script. Unfortunatley I'm getting this same issue again. This error does not occur when I build or run the app locally.

Is my package.json 
I'm using node 6.15.1
I've tried v0.3.0, v0.4.0, v1.0.0, and v2.0.0 of 
    ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile to no avail. 
I'm assuming my problem again is in some handlebars template, but unfortunately without the errors locally I can't deduce the location.

````
  "name": "~~~",
  "description": "Small description for ~~~~ goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install --allow-root"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.15.1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@newrelic/publish-sourcemap": "4.4.0",
    "active-model-adapter": "^2.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "bower": "^1.8.2",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "2.2.0",
    "broccoli-stew": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-ajax": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli": "~2.15.1",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^6.7.1",
    "ember-cli-bootstrap-sass": "git+https://github.com/~~~/ember-cli-bootstrap-sass.git",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-deploy-build": "^1.1.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-change-log": "git+https://github.com/~~~~/ember-cli-deploy-change-log.git",
    "ember-cli-deploy-display-revisions": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-gzip": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-revision-data": "git+https://github.com/ember-cli-deploy/ember-cli-deploy-revision-data.git",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3": "git+https://github.com/~~~/ember-cli-deploy-s3.git",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3-index": "git+https://github.com/~~~/ember-cli-deploy-s3-index.git",
    "ember-cli-deploy-slack": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-cli-flash": "^1.7.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.10.2",
    "ember-cli-inline-content": "^0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-loading-slider": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "^3.7.1",
    "ember-cli-phone-number": "^0.1.4",
    "ember-cli-pretender": "0.5.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.9",
    "ember-cli-sass": "^10.0.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-velocity": "^0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-version-checker": "^2.1.2",
    "ember-click-outside": "0.1.12",
    "ember-composable-helpers": "2.1.0",
    "ember-data": "~2.16.3",
    "ember-decorators": "^2.5.2",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-faker": "1.1.0",
    "ember-inflector": "^2.3.0",
    "ember-link-action": "^0.1.3",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-moment": "^7.8.1",
    "ember-new-relic": "0.6.1",
    "ember-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-simple-auth": "^1.8.2",
    "ember-source": "^2.15.3",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "~2.2.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint-config-xo": "^0.10.1",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^3.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.4",
    "jquery": "~2.2.4",
    "loader.js": "^4.7.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.16",
    "rsvp": "^4.8.4",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "velocity-animate": "^1.5.2"
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

By using urls from GitHub to pull in npm packages, you are grabbing the latest code from GitHub for those packages. That code isn't necessarily ready to be used with your other dependencies, and may have breaking API changes compared to what is in the READMEs.

If you use a specific version of these packages from npm, I think your problem will likely go away. If you are working off an internal fork, consider basing your work off the last stable release, rather than `master` of those packages.

It is possible that the deploys aren't the real problem. If you do `ember serve --production`, does the app run? The production flag will make sure that your app goes through all the same compilation and minification that `deploy` would. If running with prod doesn't work, it means that there's an issues elsewhere in your app besides those GitHub urls.

I also suggest creating a fresh 2.15 app with these dependencies to see what happens.